# Write a program to find the area of a circle, create an object (Java)

Tags: java, class

```
class circle
{
    public static void main()
    {
        circle objArea = new circle();
        objArea.area(int r);
    }
    public void area()
    {
        double A = 3.14 * r * r;
        System.out.println("The area of the circle is " + A);
    }
}
```

**I am getting the error at object call statement saying ".class required" Pls help me solve this.**

Comment: I am pretty sure that this would not even compile - that is why you do not have a `.class`.  Programming languages have specific syntax which you need to follow.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character. Variable name with lower case character.

Answer (score 1):

`objArea.area(int r);` is not valid. This is where you are calling the method so you should be passing in a value - e.g. `objArea.area(10);`

`public void area()` Your `area` method doesn't take a parameter but you expected it to (you passed one above). try `public void area(int r)`

That should get it to work but I'd go further. Make `area()` return a value rather than print it so you aren't mixing calculations etc with IO.

```
public double area(int r)
{
    double A = 3.14 * r * r;
    return A;
    // a is a bad variable name - "a" is better but something
    // descriptive like "calculated_area" is better.
    // In this case you may not even need a variable:
    // return 3.14 * r * r
}

// Caller
int radius = 10;
double answer = area(radius);
System.out.println("The area of the circle radius " + radius + " is " + answer);


`
```